# Is there a reason the standard font is a bold font?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

The standard font chosen for the body of the photography site posts looks quite heavy. Also, the choice to do this has made emboldened text in questions and answers not visibly different from the regular font. I just think it would look better at a lighter weight.

Comment: I checked the font style, it's not bolded. The font-weight is normal.

Comment: The font doesn't appear to be that heavy to me - can you clarify what browser and OS you're using?

Comment: Looks normal to me. what browser version and OS are you using?

Comment: I remember it coming up that way in an older version of Fedora with Firefox. With current (and for that matter recent) Fedora it seems fine.

Comment: Looks better now. I am 100% certain it has changed since I posted this :)

Comment: Something changed with your browser, not with the site. Good to hear it is okay now :)

Comment: Unless your issue crops up again, I'm going to mark this [status-norepro].

Comment: Aha! Its this one particular flavour of Firefox (20.0.1) I'm using (on Win7) that doesn't render the Tahoma Font correctly. I can't say its that combo though because I have the same combo at work and it renders well there. Also looks great in Chrome so Its not a problem with the Fonts on this comp. I'll just mark it up as a firefox inconsistency, I guess.